# Get specific item from list of tuples c#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
List<Tuple<int, string, int>> people = new List<Tuple<int, string, int>>();
```

Using a `dataReader`, I may populate this list with various values:

```
people.Add(new Tuple<int, string, int>(myReader.GetInt32(4), myReader.GetString(3), myReader.GetInt32(5)));
```

But then how do I loop through, getting each individual value. For example I may want to read the 3 details for a specific person. Lets say there is an ID, a name and a phone number. I want something like the following:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(people.Item1[i]); //the int
            Console.WriteLine(people.Item2[i]); //the string
            Console.WriteLine(people.Item3[i]); //the int       
        }
```

Comment: people[i].Item1, people[i].Item2, people[i].Item3

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`people` is a list, so you index into the list **first**, and then you can reference whatever item you want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    people[i].Item1;
    // Etc.
}
```

Just keep in mind the **types** that you're working with, and these kinds of mistakes will be few and far between.

```
people;          // Type: List<T> where T is Tuple<int, string, int>
people[i];       // Type: Tuple<int, string, int>
people[i].Item1; // Type: int
```

Comment: Quickest answer wins the prize

Answer (score 14):

You're indexing the wrong object.  `people` is the array that you want to index, not `Item1`.  `Item1` is simply a value on any given object in the `people` collection.  So you'd do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item1); //the int
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item2); //the string
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item3); //the int       
}
```

As an aside, I highly recommend you create an actual object to hold these values instead of a `Tuple`.  It makes the rest of the code (such as this loop) much more clear and easy to work with.  It could be something as simple as:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then the loop is greatly simplified:

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(person.SomeOtherValue);
}
```

No need for comments explaining what the values mean at this point, the values themselves tell you what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item2);
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item3);       
}
```

or using a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in people) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item2);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got to change where your indexer is, you have to put it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item1); //the int
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item2); //the string
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item3); //the int       
}
```

There you go!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item1); //the int
        Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item2); //the string
        Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item3); //the int       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the indexer back a bit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item1); //the int
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item2); //the string
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Item3); //the int       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Ctupple
{
    List<Tuple<int, string, DateTime>> tupple_list = new List<Tuple<int, string, DateTime>>();
    public void create_tupple()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            tupple_list.Add(new Tuple<int, string, DateTime>(i, "Dump", DateTime.Now));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var v in tupple_list)
        {
            sb.Append(v.Item1);
            sb.Append("    ");
            sb.Append(v.Item2);
            sb.Append("    ");
            sb.Append(v.Item3);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        int j = 0;
    }
    public void update_tupple()
    {
        var vt = tupple_list.Find(s => s.Item1 == 10);
        int index = tupple_list.IndexOf(vt);
        vt = new Tuple<int, string, DateTime>(vt.Item1, "New Value" , vt.Item3);
        tupple_list.RemoveAt(index);
        tupple_list.Insert(index,vt);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var v in tupple_list)
        {
            sb.Append(v.Item1);
            sb.Append("    ");
            sb.Append(v.Item2);
            sb.Append("    ");
            sb.Append(v.Item3);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

}
```